# Mysql remove duplicate rows base on column value but keep the latest one

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields (phonecall,calldate,checked) and I want to remove duplicate rows by the phonecall column value but not the latest one.

[image]

In this scenario I want to delete 2 rows from the first of this table.

Thanks

Comment: And which 2 rows do you want to delete?

Comment: 2 rows from the first

Comment: Share other fields as well of this table;

Comment: There is no other fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
delete A from TableX A
  left join TableX B
    on B.CallDate>A.CallDate and B.PhoneCall=A.PhoneCall
 where B.PhoneCall is not null
```

Comment: What about inner join without where?

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
delete callLog
from callLog
  inner join (
     select max(CallDate) as lastCallDate, PhoneCall
     from callLog
     group by PhoneCall
     having count(*) > 1) duplic on duplic.PhoneCall = callLog.PhoneCall
where callLog.CallDate < duplic.lastCallDate;
```